# Flask page not refreshing in the browser after xmlHttpRequest() send

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I am using an event listener to intercept a form submission, wait for a confirmation and then submit the form using xmlHttpRequest. The POST to my page seems to be working (meaning I can detect all the form fields I would expect) however, at the end of the Flask view handler code, the redirect does not cause the browser to refresh the page. In the view handler I try to redirect the page using `return redirect('/pagename')`

The positive outcome in my event listener handler code is:

```
  // The positive action was chosen
  .then(() => {
    url = event.submitter.formAction
    submit_element = event.submitter;
    len = event.srcElement.length
    const formData = new FormData();
  
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      formData.append(event.srcElement[i].name, event.srcElement[i].value )
    }
    
    const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("POST", url, true);
    request.send(formData);

  })
```

In my flask app I also have:

```
@app.after_request
def after_request(response):
    """Ensure responses aren't cached"""
    response.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
    response.headers["Expires"] = 0
    response.headers["Pragma"] = "no-cache"
    response.headers['Cache-Control'] = 'public, max-age=0'
    return response
```

If I don't intercept the form submission with the event listener then the form submission and page redirect works as expected.

Is there something else I need to include in my xmlHttpRequest.send() call to fully simulate the form submission? Any ideas about what might be going on here much appreciated.

Comment: `XMLHttpRequest` was invented to get data from server without reloading page - and it never refresh page. It only get data from server but you have to reload page on your own. You could try to use `document.location = '/pagename'` but it will load page again (without `XMLHttpRequest`). So if you want to reload page then maybe use normal `form` and normal `redirect()` without `XMLHttpRequest`. OR you should get data from server and replace in `HTML`

Comment: thanks @furas - I don't think I appreciated that about XMLHttpRequest. Would you expect the page NOT to be reloaded even if we are using a POST method in the request to send data to the server?

When you suggest using `document.location = '/pagename'` to reload the page this ,ight work in my case. Where would I add it though? Can I detect when the XMLHttpRequest has completed and do the page reload in my event listener code?

Comment: `XMLHttpRequest` was created to get data without reloading - so I expected that page NOT be reloaded. `XMLHttpRequest` has some method to detect if POST was completed - but `XMLHttpRequest` is old method and I don't remeber how to do it. I prefer modern `fetch(url,...).then(data=>{...}).catch(error=>{...})`. See Mozilla documentation about [Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

Answer (score 0):

Using the JavaScript fetch() instead of the XMLHttpRequest() worked for me to solve my issue. The fetch() function POSTS the data and I can use the .then() clause to redirect to the location after the fetch().

I was able to use code like below to POST all the fields from the form submit, intercepted by my event listener; and then force a page reload of the page that the form was submitted from.

```
              .
              .
// get url of submitting page
url = event.submitter.formAction;

// work out how many fields we have
len = event.srcElement.length;

// add each field to a formData object
const formData = new FormData();
for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  formData.append(event.srcElement[i].name, event.srcElement[i].value );
}

// post the data
response = fetch(url,
{
    body: formData,
    method: "post"
});    

response.then(response => {
  console.log(response);
  // reload the page
  document.location = response.url;

              .
              .
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I have added some additional information to my answer